# Can I move one data series down to a lower x axis, programmatically?

Tags: d3.js

I have a d3 stacked column chart that I'm very happy with. The full code is in a [JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/oa7hho9q/16/).

What I'd like to do is lop the last data series off, and set it on its own axis, but ensure that it maintains the same scale. So if this is my data:

```
var dataset = [
  // apples
  [{"x": 1, "y": 5 }, { "x": 2, "y": 4 }, { "x": 3, "y": 2 }, { "x": 4, "y": 7 }, { "x": 5, "y": 23 }],
  // oranges
  [{ "x": 1, "y": 10 }, { "x": 2, "y": 12 }, { "x": 3, "y": 19 }, { "x": 4, "y": 23 }, { "x": 5, "y": 17 }],
  // grapes
  [{ "x": 1, "y": 22 }, { "x": 2, "y": 28 }, { "x": 3, "y": 32 }, { "x": 4, "y": 35 }, { "x": 5, "y": 43 }],
  // carrots
  [{"x": 1, "y": 5 }, { "x": 2, "y": 4 }, { "x": 3, "y": 23 }, { "x": 4, "y": 2 }, { "x": 5, "y": 7 }]
];
```

I'd like to keep apples, oranges and grapes stacked, but I want carrots separated out. Carrots is always the last series. I was hoping I could draw the carrots into the same SVG with this:

```
var lower_svg = d3.select("#chart")
  .append("svg")
  .attr("width", w)
  .attr("height", b);

var lower_rects = lower_svg.selectAll("rect")
  .data(dataset[3])
  .enter()
  .append("rect")
  .attr("x", function(d, i) {
    return xScale(i);
  })
  .attr("y", h)
  .attr("height", function(d) {
    return yScale(d.y);
  })
  .attr("width", xScale.rangeBand());
```

But a) that doesn't work (it doesn't draw anything) and b) that calls on the data series 3, which happens to be the last one in this example but isn't always.

And ... if it did work it would draw the carrots twice, once stacked with the other fruits and once below. I only want to draw it once, below.

What I want is to have this chart of various fruit: https://jsfiddle.net/oa7hho9q/17/

And this chart of carrots: https://jsfiddle.net/oa7hho9q/19/

Using the same x and y scales and pulling from the same dataset, where, carrots is just the last series in the set.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have addressed your problem like this:

**Step 1:**

I pop out the carrot related data.

```
var carrots = dataset.pop(); store it in variable carrots
```

**Step 2**

I make 2 groups

```
//this g(group) will hold the stacked chart for carrot
var svgcarrot = svg.append("g").attr("transform", "translate(0,200)");
//this g(group) will hold the stacked chart for other fruits
var svg = svg.append("g").attr("transform", "translate(0,-150)");
//you may change the translate to move the chart as per your choice of positioning.
```

**Step3**

Make a function to make charts input svg group and its related dataset

```
//here svg is the group on which you wish to draw the chart.
//dataset is the data for which the chart need to be drawn.
function makeChart(dataset, svg) {
```

**Step4**

Inside your `makeChart` function your usual stack bar chart code.

```
function makeChart(dataset, svg) {
  var stack = d3.layout.stack();
  stack(dataset);//set  data
  xScale = d3.scale.ordinal()
    .domain(d3.range(dataset[0].length))
    .rangeRoundBands([0, w], 0.05);

  yScale = d3.scale.linear()
    .domain([0,
      d3.max(dataset, function(d) {
        return d3.max(d, function(d) {
          return d.y0 + d.y;
        });
      })
    ])
    .range([0, h / 2]);//2 chart so height/2
  //make groups for fruits
  var groups = svg.selectAll("g")
    .data(dataset)
    .enter()
    .append("g")
    .style("fill", function(d, i) {
      return colors(i);
    });
  //make rectangles
  var rects = groups.selectAll("rect")
    .data(function(d) {
      return d;
    })
    .enter()
    .append("rect")
    .attr("x", function(d, i) {
      return xScale(i);
    })
    .attr("y", function(d, i) {
      return h - b - (yScale(d.y0 + d.y));
    })
    .attr("height", function(d) {
      return yScale(d.y);
    })
    .attr("width", xScale.rangeBand());

}
```

**Step 5**

Now make your first chart

```
makeChart(dataset, svg);//note dataset has no carrot data as its popped in step1 also the svg container group made in step 2

makeChart([carrots], svgcarrot);//make carrot chart note the svgcarrot container group made in step 2
```

working example [here](https://jsfiddle.net/cyril123/122cg3jq/)

Comment: But ... the yScale is off -- it is relative to the available space each time. the two charts should use the same yScale.

Comment: With the help of  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36683358/how-do-i-access-the-array-sum-here/36683843 the yScale now works.

Comment: you can arrange both the charts side by side. Changing the translate of the group `var svgcarrot = svg.append("g").attr("transform", "translate(500,-150)")
var svg = svg.append("g").attr("transform", "translate(0,-150)");` mentioned in step 2.
working code https://jsfiddle.net/rojhrnm7/