# How do I access the array sum here?

Tags: arrays, d3.js

I have a data set that looks roughly like this:

```
var dataset = [
  // apples
  [{"x": 1, "y": 5 }, { "x": 2, "y": 4 }, { "x": 3, "y": 2 }, { "x": 4, "y": 7 }, { "x": 5, "y": 23 }],
  // oranges
  [{ "x": 1, "y": 10 }, { "x": 2, "y": 12 }, { "x": 3, "y": 19 }, { "x": 4, "y": 23 }, { "x": 5, "y": 17 }],
  // grapes
  [{ "x": 1, "y": 22 }, { "x": 2, "y": 28 }, { "x": 3, "y": 32 }, { "x": 4, "y": 35 }, { "x": 5, "y": 43 }]
];
```

And I need to know the highest possible sum of Y values (it happens to be the last one in the series -- `23 + 17 + 43`) -- I think that what I need to do is first use an array map to find the sums, and then take the max of those sums.

I thought I could do this with `console.log(d3.max(d3.map(d3.sum(dataset))));` but what I see in the console is just `undefined` --  my syntax is clearly wrong.

I also tried this, which is close:

```
dataset.map(function (a) {
  return d3.sum(a.map(function (d) { return d.y; }));
})
```

Which gives me the sum of each series (`Array [ 41, 81, 160 ]`) with a max of `160`, not the sum of the first items, followed by the second items (`Array [ 37, 44, 53, 65, 83]`) -- I'm looking for the latter-- the max should be `83`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`d3.zip()`](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Arrays#d3_zip) comes in handy here, since you're manipulating data based on array index.

https://jsfiddle.net/guanzo/o8voyydx/2/

```
var result = dataset.map(d=>d.map(d=>d.y))
result = d3.zip.apply(undefined,result)
result = d3.max(result.map(d=>d3.sum(d)))
console.log(result )//83
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a horrifying solution and as close to a "one-liner" as I can get.  It'll handle un-even length arrays too:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script data-require="d3@3.5.3" data-semver="3.5.3" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.3/d3.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <script>
    var dataset = [
      // apples
      [{
        "x": 1,
        "y": 5
      }, {
        "x": 2,
        "y": 4
      }, {
        "x": 3,
        "y": 2
      }, {
        "x": 4,
        "y": 7
      }, {
        "x": 5,
        "y": 23
      }],
      // oranges
      [{
        "x": 1,
        "y": 10
      }, {
        "x": 2,
        "y": 12
      }, {
        "x": 3,
        "y": 19
      }, {
        "x": 4,
        "y": 23
      }, {
        "x": 5,
        "y": 17
      }],
      // grapes
      [{
        "x": 1,
        "y": 22
      }, {
        "x": 2,
        "y": 28
      }, {
        "x": 3,
        "y": 32
      }, {
        "x": 4,
        "y": 35
      }, {
        "x": 5,
        "y": 43
      }]
    ];
  
   var l = d3.max(dataset, function(d){
     return d.length;
   }), 
   sumArr = d3.range(l).map(function(i){
     return dataset.map(function(d){
       return d[i] ? d[i].y : 0;
     });
   }).map(function(d){
     return d3.sum(d);
   });
   
  d3.select("body").text(sumArr);
    
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

---

P.S. Eric's solution is so much better...