# How do I fit these two charts onto one SVG

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm trying to create a chart that illustrates a particular discrepancy. For the sake of simplicity, let's say that I'm trying to show that overall, five charming people get way more calories from fruit than from all vegetables combined. So I want to draw two column charts on the same scale and x-axis: one that shows a breakdown, by variety, of fruits. And a second that shows the sum of all the vegetables.

With some help from [How do I access the array sum here?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36683358/how-do-i-access-the-array-sum-here/36683843) and [Can I move one data series down to a lower x axis, programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36660953/can-i-move-one-data-series-down-to-a-lower-x-axis-programmatically) I've gotten super close. But I'm having a hard time figuring out how to *insure* that both charts are visible in full.

I'm setting the width and height, and then transforming the SVG objects so that they are offset:

```
var w = 400,
    h = 600;

var svg = d3.select("#chart")
  .append("svg")
  .attr("width", w)
  .attr("height", h)

var svgcarrot = svg.append("g").attr("transform", "translate(0,100)")
var svgfruit = svg.append("g").attr("transform", "translate(0,-150)");
```

But some variations result in some of the data getting cut off. Is there any way to prevent it from getting cut off? Possibly by using math instead of arbitrary numbers in `attr("transform", "translate(0,-150)")`?

Fiddle-ready version at https://jsfiddle.net/122cg3jq/4/

Comment: Not an answer, just a comment: you are using `var svg` twice. Change the second one for something else.

Comment: @GerardoFurtado Done. New fiddle has `svgcarrot` and `svgfruit`

Answer (score 0):

The reason why both your charts are not visible when you translate it side by side.

Because for both the charts you are providing range from 0 to the width of the svg.
Now as both charts have same scale so they will take the full width.

So instead of:

```
xScale = d3.scale.ordinal()
    .domain(d3.range(dataset[0].length))
    .rangeRoundBands([0, w], 0.05);
```

Do this such that the graph takes 2.5 of the width:

```
  xScale = d3.scale.ordinal()
    .domain(d3.range(dataset[0].length))
    .rangeRoundBands([0, w/2.5], 0.05);
```

Now simply translate both groups such that they both on the same height.

```
var svgcarrot = svg.append("g").attr("transform", "translate(500,0)")//y is 0 so that both are drawn @ same height
var svg = svg.append("g").attr("transform", "translate(0,0)");//y is 0 so that both are drawn @ same height
```

working code [here](https://jsfiddle.net/sncejby9/)